# Wrap text around Image using CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, word-wrap

I want to position blockquote inside paragraphs inside columns so that text inside column would adjust to the shape of blockquote. This can be easily done in some Vector Manipulation Softwares but I want to do it via CSS or JS.

Here is an example image of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: I have no idea where to start. Its like giving an element float: middle; which is wrong syntactically. I have googled this but no success.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/float-center/

Comment: @jmeas interesting solutions. but works just with css3. maybe it is more compatible if you set the css-properties with jQuery('#l:before, #r:before').css({ 'content': "", 'width': 125, 'height': 250 });

Comment: @algorhythm There are no "CSS3" properties used in that example. Will work fine in IE 8+ and modern browsers.

Comment: How would I get some top offset in the blockquote? Negative margin-bottom isn't working.

Comment: This can be done with (multiple) CSS shapes now - see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41004410/957950) to a similar question. Support will be even better in a couple years once the CSS Shapes 2 and CSS Exclusion specs are completed and implemented.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS wrap text around centred image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267249/css-wrap-text-around-centred-image)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you're forcing a printed matter design paradigm onto the medium of the web, which has completely different systems of representing information. IMHO this is just something you should not want to do. Imagine the difficulties in making this responsive or adapt to mobile.