# how to adjust text around the image to avoid overlapping

Tags: html, css, angularjs, reactjs

[IMAGE OF THE PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOd6I.jpg)
the result is this.I want the text not to overlap with the image.

Comment: The circle are already over the text. The text are not overlaping the circle

Comment: yes but is there any workaround to solve the problem

Comment: We are not a code writing service. Please refer to [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Have you tried to do any research? What have you tried? Questions here should have a clear problem/question, with research shown, and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 0):

A little unclear on what you trying to do, but I think z-index will work:

```
            <div class="container-fluid" id="circle_div"></div>

            <div class="container" id="div">
                <div class="container box"><h3>Apple</h3>
                    <div id="box1"></div>
                    <p class="mytext">Lorem Ipsum ...Lorem Ipsum.</p>

                </div>
                <div class="container box"><h3>Orange</h3>
                    <p class="mytext">Lorem Ipsum ...Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="container box"><h3>Banana</h3>
                    <p class="mytext">Lorem Ipsum ...Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="container box"><h3>Mango</h3>
                    <p class="mytext">Lorem Ipsum ...Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <style>
                .mytext{
                    z-index:1000
                }
            </style>
```

Comment: thanku for the ans but using z-index will bring the image over the text (please see the image attached).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you want to place your image. But you can achieve the wrapping text around image using 'float' property in css.

**html:**

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/natural_beauty_highdefinition_picture_166133.jpg"/>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam cursus. Morbi ut mi.</p>
</div>
```

Css:

```
img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
    width: 160px;
    height: 150px;
}

p {
    text-align: justify;
    text-indent: 2em;
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/upasanak/ud2nqjjc/)

For more details google 'float' property in css.

Comment: have a look at the image than u might help me

Comment: You should look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267249/css-wrap-text-around-centred-image . It is similar to your issue. This might help!